# wp all import not adding products as variation

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am adding products as csv with wp all import pro, but the size and colors of the products are available, I create variations, but after the products are loaded, they are loaded as simple products, no size selection or color selection part does not appear, I wonder where is the problem with the product?
[image]

Wp all import
[image]

Idiom to ask for help for wordpress

Comment: Did you set Parent sku, under variations tab?